# SQL: get one value from one row and update another value from another row in the same table

Tags: sybase

My table looks like this:

```
EFFECTIVE_DATE    POLICY_ID    PLAN_ID    TOTAL    CODE
01/31/2017        A100         R          0.20     000
01/31/2017        A100         M          100.00   000
01/31/2017        A100         W          0.00     000
```

I need to take the row where the `PLAN_ID = R` and add the TOTAL to the row where the `PLAN_ID = M`

The result should look something like this:

```
EFFECTIVE_DATE    POLICY_ID    PLAN_ID    TOTAL    CODE
01/31/2017        A100         M          100.20   000
01/31/2017        A100         W          0.00     000
```

Comment: Please **edit** your question and show us SQL table data, not HTML tables.  I don't think anyone can read the data you currently have.  By the way, there are no embedded demos for SQL currently supported on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Your result is missing the 'R' row ... does this mean you also want to delete the 'R' row?;  Which column(s) are you using to match rows ... POLICY_ID? POLICY_ID + EFFECTIVE_DATE? some other column combo?; what happens if you have more than 1 'R' row?

Comment: More so or less. The 'R' row should get deleted. The column im using to match the rows are EFFECTIVE_DATE + POLICY_ID + PLAN_ID

Answer (score 0):

Set up some sample data:

```
use tempdb
go

if object_id('data') is not null
        drop table data
go

create table data
(EFFECTIVE_DATE datetime    not NULL
,POLICY_ID      varchar(10) not NULL
,PLAN_ID        char(1)     not NULL
,TOTAL          smallmoney  not NULL
,CODE           varchar(3)  not NULL
)
go

set nocount on
go

insert data values ('01/31/2017','A100','R',0.20,'000')
insert data values ('01/31/2017','A100','M',100.00,'000')
insert data values ('01/31/2017','A100','W',0.00,'000')
go
```

Perform the desired update/delete:

```
update  data
set     TOTAL = t1.TOTAL + t2.TOTAL

from    data t1,
        data t2

where   t1.EFFECTIVE_DATE = t2.EFFECTIVE_DATE
and     t1.POLICY_ID      = t2.POLICY_ID
and     t1.PLAN_ID        = 'M'
and     t2.PLAN_ID        = 'R'

--

delete  data
where   PLAN_ID = 'R'

--

select  convert(varchar(10),EFFECTIVE_DATE,101) as EFFECTIVE_DATE,
        POLICY_ID,
        PLAN_ID,
        TOTAL,
        CODE
from    data
order by EFFECTIVE_DATE, POLICY_ID, PLAN_ID
go

 EFFECTIVE_DATE POLICY_ID  PLAN_ID TOTAL    CODE
 -------------- ---------- ------- -------- ----
 01/31/2017     A100       M         100.20 000
 01/31/2017     A100       W           0.00 000
```

If more than one 'R' record can exist for a given EFFECTIVE_DATE + POLICY_ID pair:

```
truncate table data
go

insert data values ('01/31/2017','A100','R',0.20,'000')
insert data values ('01/31/2017','A100','R',0.11,'000')
insert data values ('01/31/2017','A100','M',100.00,'000')
insert data values ('01/31/2017','A100','W',0.00,'000')
go

update  data
set     TOTAL = t1.TOTAL + (select      sum(t2.TOTAL)
                                from    data t2
                                where   t2.EFFECTIVE_DATE = t1.EFFECTIVE_DATE
                                and     t2.POLICY_ID      = t1.POLICY_ID
                                and     t2.PLAN_ID        = 'R')
from    data t1
where   t1.PLAN_ID = 'M'

--

delete  data
where   PLAN_ID = 'R'

--

select  convert(varchar(10),EFFECTIVE_DATE,101) as EFFECTIVE_DATE,
        POLICY_ID,
        PLAN_ID,
        TOTAL,
        CODE
from    data
order   by EFFECTIVE_DATE, POLICY_ID, PLAN_ID
go

 EFFECTIVE_DATE POLICY_ID  PLAN_ID TOTAL    CODE
 -------------- ---------- ------- -------- ----
 01/31/2017     A100       M         100.31 000
 01/31/2017     A100       W           0.00 000
```

NOTES:

- the second query works for both single and multiple 'R' records (per EFFECTIVE_DATE + POLICY_ID pairs)
- user should add additional code to provide transaction management and error handling